# Extract property name and value from multiple property tags

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this XML structure as shown below. I need to find the object block that has property value of "Zipcode:" and get the value of OrderID two lines before and the next line that has the actual zipcode value.

End result is I need the OrderID value and the zipcode pair (Smith-123,05403).

```xml
<Object name="CustomDataList" type="TDM_List_CustomData">
  <List name="Items">
    <Object type="TDM_Item_CustomData">
      <Property name="CustomDataID" value="CD156FC1461C674F2CAFC181013FCB9822" />
      <Property name="OrderID" value="Smith-123" />
      <Property name="FieldID" value="{CCC2CBB8-BEAA-4E9B-AF2D-3E32B68821D0}" />
      <Property name="FieldCaption" value="" />
      <Property name="Value" value="35082_Site20" />
      <Property name="Kind" value="cdkInternal" />
    </Object>
    <Object type="TDM_Item_CustomData">
      <Property name="CustomDataID" value="CD58AFECE84FF24D53AFB5E2F0411EE3C9" />
      <Property name="OrderID" value="Smith-123" />
      <Property name="FieldID" value="DS_CustomizableFieldZB99" />
      <Property name="FieldCaption" value="Zipcode:" />
      <Property name="Value" value="05403" />
      <Property name="Kind" value="cdkPublic" />
    </Object>
    <Object type="TDM_Item_CustomData">
      <Property name="CustomDataID" value="CD5E584899B6274F88B05D459863006914" />
      <Property name="OrderID" value="Smith-123" />
      <Property name="FieldID" value="{62D7C382-9754-454D-A4D5-04437BFC5FE4}" />
      <Property name="FieldCaption" value="" />
      <Property name="Value" value="False" />
      <Property name="Kind" value="cdkInternal" />
    </Object>
```

I have some very beginner code below that I used previously where I was looking for only a single property name value pair on a single line, but I can't figure out how to read lines before and after my "zipcode" pointer.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pwrshell\*\*.xml | foreach {
    echo $_.FullName

    [xml]$doc = Get-Content $_
    $OrderID = $doc.SelectSingleNode("//Property[@name = 'OrderID']")

    if ($OrderID) {
        echo "OrderID: $($OrderID.value)"
    } else {
        echo "OrderID not found"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible way to get the desired values. First, locate the `Object` element where 'FieldCaption' value equals 'Zipcode:' :

```
$query = "//Object[Property[@name = 'FieldCaption' and @value = 'Zipcode:']]"
$zipcodeObj = $doc.SelectSingleNode($query)
```

From that `Object`, then you can easily get `Property` element by `name` attribute using relative XPath expression :

```
$orderID = $zipcodeObj.SelectSingleNode("Property[@name = 'OrderID']/@value")
$zipcode = $zipcodeObj.SelectSingleNode("Property[@name = 'Value']/@value")
```

Output :

```
λ echo $orderID.value, $zipcode.value
Smith-123
05403
```